# How to decide which check engine reading is faulty?

Tags: honda, fuel-system, cel, sensor, crv

03 Honda CR-V.  Check engine light just came on.  O’reilys scanner gave a long list of readings... wondering if I should try bring it in or figure out a way to narrow it down beforehand.[image]

Comment: Are you having any actual problems with the car, as in rough running, stalling, etc? What made you read the codes in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

1. clear the list and see what comes back as some are often historical,
2. check the fuels supply system thoroughly as all those are related - maybe there is one fault and it is triggering all the others.

Comment: I found out it was the evap filter.  Thank you for the information though, I didn’t know there was a history function to the read out that would retain issues from the past.

Answer (score 0):

The list you got all look related to having a pressure leak in the fuel tank system, which is letting air in/out.  A common reason for this is not putting on the gas cap tight enough, or a failed seal in the gas cap.

A good first place to start is checking/replacing the gas cap. Some shops may have a tool for testing gas caps.

If the car is driving fine, the main hazard with this issue is that some gas fumes could be escaping from the tank.